# Is there any difference between 'ree' and 'denove'?

Tags: word-difference

Is there any difference between *ree* and *denove*? I mostly see *denove* used, but *ree* seems like a logical substitute for such cases.

Answer (score 7):

*Denove* is the traditional way of saying ”again” in Esperanto. *Ree* is made from the prefix *re-*, so it’s a bit more ”fresh and slangy”, I’d say.

You could compare it with *antaŭa* versus *eksa*: *Mi estis tie kun mia antaŭa koramikino* vs. *Mi estis tie kun mia eksa koramikino.* The former sounds a bit more formal, but the difference in meaning is slight.

Hooray for synonyms, I’d say! :-) Which one to use depends on the setting. I think I’d go with the second phrase below:

1. Li ree restartigis sian komputilon.
2. Li denove restartigis sian komputilon.

Also note the Esperantigo of the great fantasy classic *The Hobbit, or There and Back Again*: ”*La Hobito aŭ Tien kaj **Reen***.”
*Tien kaj Denoven* would be wrong, so the synonymity is not perfect in this case. :-)

Comment: +1 for the Hobbit mention... Also, as an aside: there are practically no perfect synonyms in any language, as that would be wasteful. There are degrees of similarity in meaning and usage (which includes style & register, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is a substitute: http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/re.html#re.0e

I like **denove** better because it is easy for me to say.